# Dynamic Links from Excel to Sharepoint

Tags: excel, sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

Good morning, code gurus. I have a question regarding SharePoint.

I am finding myself in need of creating a dynamic link from an Excel file to a SharePoint Workflow. I'm new to SharePoint programming/design in general, so I'm not exactly sure if this is possible, or if there are better ways to do it. For example, please see below:

I have a SharePoint site that I've created a workflow in. This workflow will be used to email a list of people regarding some regulatory information that they have to confirm. I'm wanting to use a single excel file that I can regularly update and link directly to the SharePoint. This file would ideally be referenced every time the workflow is activated/kicked off so it can pull in the email addresses and then use that list to create the To: section of the email.

Thank you!

Comment: any example to share ?

Comment: Unfortunately not. I'm using SharePoint 2013 and it's all very conceptual right now. There's not a ton of coding on there. It's just a GUI interface.

To give a high-level example, the process would take a list of email addresses (IE: Test1@Test.com, Test2@Test.com, Test3@Test.com) and populate them into the "TO:" section of an email that will be automated by SharePoint itself.

Comment: I understand that the excel file is you 'backend', n the sharepoint is you 'frontend' (or something like that.., If.. I get it right..) .. so the best thing about testing an idea is start small... use simple 3 column excel.. and build your sharepoint info 'loading/viewing' part. || Once done test it.. then only expand.. || Of course the other way around is to pay some people to do it.. (backend only..) then || If you only need mailto... then here is a reference I stumbled upon b4.. https://www.labnol.org/internet/email/learn-mailto-syntax/6748/ hope it helps.. ( :